Find the height of the cone.

A right circular cone has certain volume of water. The cone has two orientations upright and inverted. The water level in upright and inverted are $2cm$ and $6cm$ respectively. Find the height of the cone.
(Note : The figures are not to scale.)
My Attempt : We have two things (1) Cones are similar (2) Volume of water is same in both situations of the cone. So we have to find relationship between radii of water levels and heights of whole cone.
Let $r_1$ and $r_2$ be the radii of water levels of upright and inverted cones and $H$ and $R$ be the height and radius of whole cone. Due to similarity of cones,  $2:H :: r_1:R ; 6:H :: r_2:R$ and Volume of water is same in both situations of the cone then $\frac{1}{3}π{r_1}^2H_1 = \frac{1}{3}π{r_2}^2H_2$, Where $H_1$ and $H_2$ is partial heights of upright and inverted cones respectively. But I'm unable to set relationship between these cones. Please help me.

Have you used that the depths of upright vs inverted cones are not comparable in that only one measures from the apex?

Can you share the figures?
